# SheetJS: Error: require() of ES Module /node_modules/xlsx/dist/cpexcel.full.mjs not supported

Tags: import, nestjs, xlsx, commonjs, sheetjs

I am using NestJS/TypeScript and one of my service files has the following [imports](https://docs.sheetjs.com/docs/getting-started/installation/nodejs#esm-import) which were taken from their (SheetJS) documentation page.

```
/* load the codepage support library for extended support with older formats  */
import * as cpexcel from 'xlsx/dist/cpexcel.full.mjs';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx/xlsx.mjs';

/* load 'fs' for readFile and writeFile support */
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { DSRequestContextService } from '@shared/services/context/context_service';
import { DSLogService } from '@shared/services/log/log.service';

XLSX.set_fs(fs);

XLSX.stream.set_readable(Readable);

XLSX.set_cptable(cpexcel);
```

However I get the following error:

> [ERROR] 18:11:27 Error: require() of ES Module /mnt/d/Repos/document-engine/node_modules/xlsx/dist/cpexcel.full.mjs not supported.
> Instead change the require of /mnt/d/Repos/document-engine/node_modules/xlsx/dist/cpexcel.full.mjs to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.

Anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

since your project is using CJS, you should use the `import()` expressions to load ESM-only modules, as described in NodeJS docs: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#import-expressions